# Await all Tasks in the list, and after that update the list base on task result

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to run all tasks with `WhenAll` (not one by one).
But after that I need to update list (`LastReport` property) base on result.

I think I have solution but I would like to check if there is better way.

Idea is to:

- Run all tasks
- Remember relation between configuration and task
- Update configuration

My solution is:

```
var lastReportAllTasks = new List<Task<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
var configurationTaskRelation = new Dictionary<int, Task<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
foreach (var configuration in MachineConfigurations)
{
    var task = machineService.GetReports(configuration);
    lastReportAllTasks.Add(task);
    configurationTaskRelation.Add(configuration.Id, task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(lastReportAllTasks);
foreach (var configuration in MachineConfigurations)
{
    var lastReportTask = configurationTaskRelation[configuration.Id];
    configuration.LastReport = await lastReportTask;
}
```

Comment: WHy use async if you're going to wait for everything? :)

Comment: did you try AsyncState: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.asyncstate(v=vs.110).aspx ? Something like this: `var task = machineService.GetReports(configuration);task.AsyncState = configuration;
                lastReportAllTasks.Add(task);` and retrieve back after `When.All`

Comment: After using `await Task.WhenAll` you don't need to `await` again for task, just use their `.Result`

Comment: @ EpicKip I await for result, but UI thread is free to do other stuff. Also many task are running at the same time, so I have  better performance.

Comment: @EpicKip this is a vaild and very common usage. All tasks run *concurrently*. Awaiting is asynchronous. Best case, `await Task.WhenAll()` will only take as long as the slowest task

Comment: @Fabio I know, but I like this more. It is cleaner to await. At least my opinion.

Comment: It not about "cleaner" it about that `Task` already completed just use `LastReport = lastReportTask.Result`

Comment: @Fabio You don't even need `WhenAll` in the first place.  *That* is the redundant line of code here.  Each task is already being awaited in the loop, so there's no reason to await them all before starting the loop (as there's nothing in that loop that is harmed by starting it before all operations are done).

Comment: Actually, there are valid use cases for `Task.WhenAll` when we want to execute only when all the tasks are finished. In your case, if you want to use `Task.WhenAll` and still able to retrieve the original `configuration`, you can try  `AsyncState`

Comment: @Servy - when you use `Task.WhenAll` you will return execution back to caller and return here only when all tasks completes.

Comment: @Fabio Which is the same behavior you get out of awaiting each of the tasks in a loop, which is what's also being done.  It will return execution back to the caller as soon as it reaches a task that isn't already complete, and won't process the results of any task until it has completed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My understanding was if you await the 1 method being called it will wait so it would be the same as calling the method not async. But its understandable if you run multiple tasks at once

Comment: @EpicKip even in that case it would not be same. While you 'await' for result the thread is NOT waiting. This is very useful in desktop application where you have only one UI thread.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Ah ok so they won't block the ui?

Comment: @EpicKip Yes that is the point.

Comment: @EpicKip Try it and find out for yourself.  I'd suggest doing a bit of experimenting with tasks, rather than commenting about the behavior of them if you haven't used them before.

Comment: @Servy - if you await tasks in the loop they will run one after other.

Comment: @Servy I've used them before but to run methods concurrently not to 'unblock' the ui thread. But then I found out the extra uses here so I thought it'd be smart to take the opportunity to learn something

Comment: @Fabio The tasks are all started before the loop, so no, they aren't.

Comment: @EpicKip This isn't about tasks, this is about `await`.  The *only* purpose of `await` is to construct asynchronous workflows.  If you're constructing synchronous operations (even if they're doing some work in parallel) there's not only no reason to use `await`, but you're almost certainly going to be introducing bugs in your code by using it, so it's important to *not* use it in a synchronous program.

Comment: @Servy I could still learn something so... and I had to use await before when I needed certain data from other tasks to continue. Why are we even arguing, I found out I was wrong -> learned something -> move on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Select` function can be asynchronous itself. You can await the report and return both the configuration and result in the same result object (anonymous type or tuple, whatever you prefer) :

```
var tasks=MachineConfigurations.Select(async conf=>{
                       var report= await machineService.GetReports(conf);
                       return new {conf,report});
var results=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
foreach(var pair in results)
{
    pair.conf.LastReport=pair.report;
}
```

**EDIT - Loops and error handling**

As Servy suggested, `Task.WhenAll` can be ommited and awaiting can be moved inside the loop :

```
foreach(var task in tasks)
{   
    var pair=await task;
    pair.conf.LastReport=pair.report;
}
```

The tasks will still execute concurrently. In case of exception though, some configuration objects will be modified and some not.

In general, this would be an ugly situation, requiring extra exception handling code to clean up the modified objects. Exception handling is a lot easier when modifications are done *on-the-side* and finalized/applied when the happy path completes. That's one reason why updating the Configuration objects inside the `Select()` requires careful consideration.

In *this particular case* though it may be better to "skip" the failed reports, possibly move them to an error queue and reprocess them at a later time. It may be better to have partial results than no results at all, as long as this behaviour is expected:

```
foreach(var task in tasks)
{   
    try
    {
        var pair=await task;
        pair.conf.LastReport=pair.report;
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //Make sure the error is logged
        Log.Error(exc);
        ErrorQueue.Enqueue(new ProcessingError(conf,ex);
    }
}
//Handle errors after the loop
```

**EDIT 2 - Dataflow**

For completeness, I *do* have several thousand ticket reports to generate each day, and each GDS call (the service through which every travel agency sells tickets) takes considerable time. I can't run *all* requests at the same time - I start getting server serialization errors if I try more than 10 concurrent requests. I can't *retry* everything either.

In this case I used TPL DataFlow combined with some [Railway oriented programming tricks](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/). An ActionBlock with a DOP of 8 processes the ticket requests. The results are wrapped in a `Success` class and sent to the next block. Failed requests and exceptions are wrapped in a `Failure` class and sent to another block. Both classes inherit from IFlowEnvelope which has a `Successful` flag. Yes, that's F# Discriminated Union envy.

This is combined with some retry logic for timeouts etc.

In pseudocode the pipeline looks like this :

```
var reportingBlock=new TransformBlock<Ticket,IFlowEnvelope<TicketReport>(reportFunc,dopOptions);
var happyBlock = new ActionBlock<IFlowEnvelope<TicketReport>>(storeToDb);
var errorBlock = new ActionBlock<IFlowEnvelope<TicketReport>>(logError);

reportingBlock.LinkTo(happyBlock,linkOptions,msg=>msg.Success);
reportingBlock.LinkTo(errorBlock,linkOptions,msg=>!msg.Success);

foreach(var ticket in tickets)
{
    reportingBlock.Post(ticket);
}
```

`reportFunc` catches any exceptions and wraps them as `Failure<T>` objects:

```
async Task<IFlowEnvelope<Ticket,TicketReport>> reportFunc(Ticket ticket)
{
    try
    {
        //Do the heavy processing
        return new Success<TicketReport>(report);
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //Construct an error message, msg
        return new Failure<TicketReport>(report,msg);
    }
}
```

The real pipeline includes steps that parse daily reports and individual tickets. Each call to the GDS takes 1-6 seconds so the complexity of the pipeline is justified.

Comment: You can do just `Select(conf => new { conf, ReportTask =  macnineService.GetReports(conf)})` and then `await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(task => task.ReportTask)`.

Comment: No, because `GetReports` is the asynchronous function. Who is going to await *it* and retrieve its results? The point is that `Select()` returns the configuration *and* the resulting report, in an async manner

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` will  await on all tasks

Comment: *Which* tasks? `GetReports` returns the task. Without awaiting, the `Select()` call would return an `IEnumerable<>` of `Configuration,Task<Report>`, not tasks

Comment: Fabio is right. You can call await Task.WhenAll() with tasks.Select(task => task.ReportTask) as an argument. But don't forget to make the tasks a List instead of IEnumerable

Comment: @Artemious no. That would *lose* the pairing of reports and configurations. The whole point is to get the configuration and results *together*, not have to search for the correct Configuration afterwards. And using a list is pointless - Neither `Task.WhenAll` nor the loop require a List

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, they don't require, but you will lose the results, if you don't convert the tasks into a List. See my answer. The results will stay in taskResultsWithConfiguration in Task property. The will not be lost.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can of course just omit the `WhenAll` call entirely, and just await the task in the loop when assigning the result, and there you go, you're waiting for the task and unwrapping the result all in one, with even less code.  It would also have the benefit of compiling, unlike the code in your answer.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, I think you misunderstand one thing. When you call `await Task.WhenAll()`, you don't have to save the array it returns. This method simply waits for all the tasks passed to it. It changes the state of each Task. And then you can do stuff with its result.

Comment: @Artemious I *want* to get the array so I don't have to search for the results *again*.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, why would you want to get the array? Does it contain millions of records?

Comment: @Servy yes, although that would have different error behaviour. If one task fails, WhenAll also fails and no modification is made. By awaiting inside the loop *some* configurations would get updated and some not

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure, if that's a problem.

Comment: @Artemious Sure you can.  `WhenAll` is generic, and so can take a sequence of tasks of *any* type.  That's what it means to be generic.  Likewise, `await` is designed to be able to await a `Task<T>` for any `T`, not just certain kinds.

Comment: @Artemious even if that's true, you can change it quickly to a Tuple or ValueTuple

Comment: @Artemious No, it won't.  In the `GetReports` method you just showed it will successfully return a `Task` that will be in the faulted state, which this code will handle as expected.

Comment: @Artemious that's a comment for the OP. Personally, I use dataflow and some railway oriented concepts to handle several thousand ticket records every day. Exception handling was never mentioned by the OP, although it *is* a valid concern

Comment: Nice functional implementation with C#, why not writing same logic in F# and use in C# code. "Injecting" this way F# to C# project will open "mind/eyes" for other developers in the team :)

Comment: @Fabio I do use F# in various places. Unfortunately, that's not the only thing I do so I haven't had the time to move more dataflow parts to F# yet. I started using F# after I had created the first 50 versions of the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need Lists or Dictionaries. Why not simple loop which updates `LastReport` with results

```
foreach (var configuration in MachineConfigurations)
{
    configuration.LastReport = await machineService.GetReports(configuration);
}
```

For executing all reports "in parallel"

```
Func<Configuration, Task> loadReport = 
    async config => config.LastReport = await machineService.GetReports(config);

await Task.WhenAll(MachineConfigurations.Select(loadReport));
```

And very poor try to be more functional.

```
Func<Configuration, Task<Configuration>> getConfigWithReportAsync = 
    async config => 
    {            
        var report = await machineService.GetReports(config);
        return new Configuration
        {
            Id = config.Id,
            LastReport = report
        };
    }

var configsWithUpdatedReports = 
    await Task.WhenAll(MachineConfigurations.Select(getConfigWithReportAsync));
```

Comment: This would execute one report at a time. Which may be the correct option if the report engine can only process one report at a time, even asynchronously. The OP did say `I want to run all tasks with WhenAll (not one by one)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - updated with approach for executing reports in parallel

Comment: I feel weird whenever I see code in `Select` that causes side effects. I wouldn't mind if the function was called `Iter` function like F#'s `Seq.iter`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - agree about side effect. OP's code updating state of provided `Configuration` - so will fit his requirement :)

Comment: Your "functional" approach isn't functional at all.  You're still applying the exact same side effect in the exact same manner.  A functional approach would be constructing a new object instead of mutating an existing one.

Comment: Another consideration is that an error will leave the configurations up to the one that failed modified. Things become a lot more interesting once you consider error handling. Is stop on first error OK? Skip and log failures? Rollback everything?

Comment: Updated with actually functional approach

Comment: @Servy Fabio understands this, if you check the comment right before yours. And F# itself has a `Seq.iter` and `AsyncSeq.iter` for such cases. If there was an `Enumerable.Iter` there wouldn't be any problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Before my comment the answer was asserting that the approach was functional, despite not actually being functional.  As for those two methods, those *aren't* functional operations.  If there was such a method *it would still have all of the same problems*.  Now that's not to say that there's wrong with having an imperative, rather than functional, program, what's wrong is claiming that the imperative program is a functional program.

Comment: @Servy this discussion is so interesting that I invited a few functional friends. Wonder if they show up

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Linq;

var taskResultsWithConfiguration = MachineConfigurations.Select(conf => 
    new { Conf = conf, Task = machineService.GetReports(conf) }).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(taskResultsWithConfiguration.Select(pair => pair.Task));

foreach (var pair in taskResultsWithConfiguration)
      pair.Conf.LastReport = pair.Task.Result;
```

Comment: You may want to split the first line into a `select` and a `Task.WhenAll` line so it doesn't require scrolling

Comment: Now that I see what each line does - no. You don't need .Result or Task.Run. `GetReports` is *already* asynchronous